# Meaning of effective inductance for parallel inductors with perfect coupling

Tags: electric-circuits

We know the effective inductance of 2 parallel inductors is proportional to the product of the 2 inductances minus off the square of the mutual inductance, for both aiding and opposing configuration. However, when the magnetic flux coupling between the 2 inductors is perfect (coupling constant k=1), the effective inductance becomes zero by the equations. How to interpret this result and understand what happen physically with zero effective inductance? When the effective inductance is zero, does it not imply that the total magnetic flux is zero for any total current flowing in the 2 parallel inductors configuration?

opposing parallel inductors : $$\frac{(L_1L_2-M^2)}{L_1+L_2-2M}$$
aiding parallel inductors : $$\frac{(L_1L_2-M^2)}{L_1+L_2+2M}$$
where $$M=k\sqrt{L_1L_2}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find the formula? It can't be completely general, since it is easy to imagine both inductors of same dimensions being very close to each other and thus forming effectively one inductor with twice as large cross-section of the winding, which will have similar self-inductance to self-inductance of the original inductor. I.e. not going to zero even though $k \to 1$.

Comment: These are widely known formulae available in any introductory electrical engineering text books. These formulae can be easily derived just by applying the Faraday's and Lenz's law on the coupling inductors knowing how much magnetic flux coupling is there and if the mutual flux coupled is in the same or opposite direction to the self-flux of each inductor.

Answer (score 1):

> When the effective inductance is zero, does it not imply that the total magnetic flux is zero for any total current flowing in the 2 parallel inductors configuration?

Yes that is exactly what is happening, and it is why the net inductance is 0.

If the inductors are identical, and perfectly coupled, and they are in opposing configuration, then the flux in core 1 (for example) is equal to the flux caused by the current in coil 1, plus the flux caused by the current in coil 2. Since these are equal and opposite, the net flux is zero. By symmetry, the same applies to the flux in core 2.

Since the flux is zero, no energy is stored. And therefore no voltage across the coils is needed to build up the stored energy as the current increases. Therefore the effective inductance is zero.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. But the baffling part is the effective inductance is still zero so long as the coupling is perfect (k=1), and it is the same even if the 2 inductors are not identical, also independent of the parallel configuration (aiding or opposing). Is there a physical picture that one could visualize for the net zero inductance under this more general condition?

Comment: @CWC, I think it's not possible for $k=1$ if the two inductors aren't identical (or at least there is a certain symmetry in the structure). But let me think about why that should be. One thing is that most EE's think in terms of the equation you gave, $M = k\sqrt{L_1 L_2}$, but from a physics point of view it might make more sense to think of $k$ as the derived parameter with $k=\frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}$.